# Count inputs number onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count

i have a little problem with my code, i need to count inputs when change the value, my code is working but when i used the increase button the count dont change the value.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="input-group input-number-group">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
  </div>
  <input class="input-number" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="1000"  onchange="count(this.value);">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="input-group input-number-group">
<input class="input-number" type="text" id="totalcount" placeholder="0" />
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS CODE:

```
$('.input-number-increment').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parents('.input-number-group').find('.input-number');
  var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
  $input.val(val + 1);
});

$('.input-number-decrement').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parents('.input-number-group').find('.input-number');
  var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
  $input.val(val - 1);
})

/* Count. */
function count(value) {
    var Total = 0;  
    value = parseInt(value); // Convertir a numero entero (número).
    Total = document.getElementById('totalcount').value;
    // Valida y pone en cero "0".
    Total = (Total == null || Total == undefined || Total == "") ? 0 : Total;
    /* Variable genrando la suma. */
    Total = (parseInt(Total) + parseInt(value));
    // Escribir el resultado en una etiqueta "span".
    document.getElementById('totalcount').value = Total;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1hs904b/)

I need to count when i press the + or rest when i press - button, any idea?

Thank so much.

Comment: Should these $input.val(val + 1)
be this: $input.value(val + 1) ?

Comment: Could you clarify?
Because I didn't get the main idea!

Comment: @cullanrocks Hello, the buttons are ok, the problem its the count and rest. Look https://jsfiddle.net/k1hs904b/ if you write a number the count work but if you use the buttons + or - the count dont change.

Comment: Sure friend @AdnaneAr look at here https://jsfiddle.net/k1hs904b/ if you write the number the count change the value on input totalcount but if you use the button the input dont change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `onchange` event listener is triggered when the user changes the input by typing. Therefore `.val()` wont cause it to fire up.

You can easily trigger the onchange event manually by adding

```
$(".input-number").change();
```

to the desired functions in your code.

In your specific case this should do the trick:

```
$('.input-number-increment').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parents('.input-number-group').find('.input-number');
  var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
  $input.val(val + 1);
  $(".input-number").change();
});

$('.input-number-decrement').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parents('.input-number-group').find('.input-number');
  var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
  $(".input-number").change();
})
```

Now your count function will execute when the user clicks the increment and decrement buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working great!! 

But now i see one more problem, i need to reset the count in every click. If is possible? if i added 2 inputs when i click the + or - button the result is the old value + the new values of the inputs.

Comment: Fixed!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked out! if you can accept the answer  :)